# Incompatibilidade de arquitetura entre drive e aplicativo

Tags: python-3.x, odbc

Estou tentando acessar os dados de um banco usando pyodbc com esse código:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=banco;uid=usuario;pwd=senha")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Mas quando executo da esse erro:

> pyodbc.Error: ('IM014', '[IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] O
>   DSN especificado contém uma incompatibilidade de arquiteturas entre o
>   Driver e o Aplicativo (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Alguém sabe onde posso corrigir essa incompatibilidade?

Comment: Se perceber bem inglês, talvez estes links ajudem https://dacosta9.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/error-im014-microsoftodbc-driver-manager-the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-application/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395492/error-im014-microsoftodbc-driver-manager-the-specified-dsn-contains-an-arc

Comment: Obrigado Miguel.
Pelo que eu entendi, eu preciso mudar o driver obbc32 para o de 64. Na máquina que eu estou usando já existe esse arquivo: c:\windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe, você sabe me dizer onde eu mudo essa configuração?

Comment: não faço ideia, procurei por esses links mas nunca passei por isso

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi.

A solução foi realmente baixar um drive de 64bit (arquitetura da minha máquina) e configurar uma nova conexão, mais ou menos como é feito nesse [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5lH3y_mPCI).